# How to know id number for new record

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

TableA:

```
id(auto numbering)  |   value
--------------------+----------
1                   |    100
2                   |    200
3                   |    100
4                   |    500
```

In Visual Studio C#

```
insert into tableA (name) values (300)
```

How to know the `id` number (auto numbering) for new record in C#?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql

Comment: `insert into tableA (name) 
values(300);select scope_identity();`

Comment: Where I put the sentence??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS:

```
    con.Open();
    string sql = "INSERT INTO Table(col2) output INSERTED.id VALUES(@value)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", "300");

    int new_id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); // here is the new id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a stored procedure like:

**SQL**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NameOfProcedure
(
    @value INT = NULL,
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tableA
    (
        name
    )
    OUTPUT INSERTED.IDCol
    VALUES
    (
        @value
    )
END
GO
```

**C#**

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("NameOfProcedure", connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", whateverValue);

var result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: creating a stored procedure everytime is impractical

Comment: You don't need the procedure. Using `output` should work just fine anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Option:
You can do it also in Query:

```
select top 1 id from yourtable order by id desc
```

But if you need this in your Code Behind:

copy that query to your Project Code.

```
public static int ExecuteQuery()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your connection String here"))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select top 1 id from yourtable order by id desc";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
```

to use:

```
Int id = ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Not at all true because it doesn't cater for concurrency.

Answer (score -2):

one way is to use the `@@Identity` property

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your connection String here"))
{
        con.Open();
        string sql = "INSERT INTO Table(col1,col2,col3) VALUES(@eimg, @etype, @flag) SELECT @@IDENTITY";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eimg", imgByte);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@etype", 4);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flag", false);
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

`@@identity` gives the last inserted row id in the current session and table.

for more information check this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103610/Difference-between-IDENTITY-SCOPE-IDENTITY-IDENT-C) on various methods to retrieve last inserted id.

Comment: If you have a trigger on `Table` that in turn insert into another table with an identity column `@@identity` has the value from the insert in the trigger not from the insert to `Table`. Better to use `scope_identity()` instead.

Comment: but there is no mention of any trigger in the question. additionaly i have provided the link in the answer for the the asker to choose what he wants to use him self.

Comment: How do you know there will not be one in the future?

Comment: then he can use the link and decide for himself.

Comment: The description for `scope_identity()` is wrong in that link. This is wrong "but if a trigger or a user defined function is affected on the same table that produced the value returns that identity record then SCOPE_IDENTITY returns that identity record which is created by trigger or a user defined function."